# How much water evaporates in a vacuum before freezing?

Tags: physical-chemistry, energy, phase

I placed a container with 1000 grams (1 kg) of water at room temperature (20 degrees Celsius) inside a vacuum at 0.03 atm pressure. The water boiled for a few seconds then froze solid.
I need to calculate how much water evaporated before freezing occurred. Anyone know a formula I could use?

Comment: At .03 atm and 20 °C the water will not boil at all. So, your "observations" are doubtful.

Comment: Extract the ice only and weight it.
1000 grams - Ice mass = Vaporized Water mass

Answer (score 7):

For a quick and dirty estimate of the evaporated fraction $x$, you might want to ignore the temperature changes as well as the temperature dependencies of the involved quantities (in particular if the initial temperature is already close to the freezing point) and just balance the enthalpy of vaporization $\Delta_\text{vap}H$ of the evaporating water and the enthalpy of fusion $\Delta_\text{fus}H$ of the freezing water:

$$\Delta_\text{vap}H\approx\Delta_\text{fus}H$$

Then, the evaporated fraction may be estimated from tabulated values for the specific enthalpies $\Delta h$ or molar enthalpies $\Delta H_\mathrm m$ as follows:

$$\begin{align}
x\cdot\Delta_\text{vap}h&\approx(1-x)\cdot\Delta_\text{fus}h\\[6pt]
x&\approx\frac{\Delta_\text{fus}h}{\Delta_\text{fus}h+\Delta_\text{vap}h}
\end{align}$$

or

$$\begin{align}
x\cdot\Delta_\text{vap}H_\mathrm m&\approx(1-x)\cdot\Delta_\text{fus}H_\mathrm m\\[6pt]
x&\approx\frac{\Delta_\text{fus}H_\mathrm m}{\Delta_\text{fus}H_\mathrm m+\Delta_\text{vap}H_\mathrm m}
\end{align}$$

For example, simply using the first values that I could find, which are the molar enthalpy of vaporization at $T=25\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ of $\Delta_\text{vap}H_\mathrm m=43.98\ \mathrm{kJ\ mol^{-1}}$<sup>[1]</sup> and the molar enthalpy of fusion at $T=0\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ of $\Delta_\text{fus}H_\mathrm m=6.01\ \mathrm{kJ\ mol^{-1}}$<sup>[2]</sup>:

$$\begin{align}
x&\approx\frac{\Delta_\text{fus}H_\mathrm m}{\Delta_\text{fus}H_\mathrm m+\Delta_\text{vap}H_\mathrm m}\\[6pt]
&\approx\frac{6.01\ \mathrm{kJ\ mol^{-1}}}{6.01\ \mathrm{kJ\ mol^{-1}+43.98\ \mathrm{kJ\ mol^{-1}}}}\\[6pt]
&\approx0.12
\end{align}$$

Thus, about $12\ \%$ of the water have to evaporate in order to completely freeze the remaining water.

---

A better result may be obtained from the enthalpy balance for the initial and final state. If the process is fast or the system is thermally isolated, the system cannot exchange heat with the environment and the enthalpy balance is given as:

$$\begin{align}
h_0&=x\cdot h_\text{vapour} + (1-x)\cdot h_\text{ice}\\[6pt]
x&=\frac{h_0-h_\text{ice}}{h_\text{vapour}-h_\text{ice}}
\end{align}$$

where
$h_0$ is the specific enthalpy of liquid water at the initial state,
$h_\text{vapour}$ is the specific enthalpy of the evaporated water at the final state, and
$h_\text{ice}$ is the specific enthalpy of the frozen water at the final state.

(Note that the specific enthalpy $h$ is a state function that depends only on the equilibrium state of the system and does not depend on the path by which the system arrived at that state. Therefore, the exact changes of the variables, i.e. temperature, pressure, enthalpy of vaporization, enthalpy of fusion, specific heat capacities and masses of liquid water, ice, and vapour, during the course of the experiment are not relevant.)

For example, for liquid water at the initial temperature of $T_0=20\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ and an assumed pressure of $p_0=1\ \mathrm{bar}=100\ \mathrm{kPa}$, the specific enthalpy of liquid water is $h_0=84.01\ \mathrm{kJ\ kg^{-1}}$<sup>[3]</sup>

At a final temperature of $T=0\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$, the saturation pressure of vapour in equilibrium with ice is $p=0.61115\ \mathrm{kPa}$. The corresponding specific enthalpies of ice and vapour are $h_\text{ice}=-333.47\ \mathrm{kJ\ kg^{-1}}$<sup>[4]</sup> and $h_\text{vapour}=2500.90\ \mathrm{kJ\ kg^{-1}}$<sup>[4]</sup>, respetively.

Therefore, the evaporated fraction can be calculated as

$$\begin{align}
x&=\frac{h_0-h_\text{ice}}{h_\text{vapour}-h_\text{ice}}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{84.01\ \mathrm{kJ\ kg^{-1}}-(-333.47\ \mathrm{kJ\ kg^{-1}})}{2500.90\ \mathrm{kJ\ kg^{-1}}-(-333.47\ \mathrm{kJ\ kg^{-1}})}\\[6pt]
&=0.147
\end{align}$$

Thus, about $14.7\ \%$ of the water have to evaporate in order to completely freeze the remaining water. Note that this value is larger than the above-mentioned quick estimate since it includes the amount of water that has to be evaporated in order to cool the water from $T_0=20\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ to $T=0\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$, which has been ignored for the first estimate.

---

Note that reducing the pressure to $p=0.03\ \mathrm{atm}$ for liquid water with an initial temperature of $T_0=20\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ (both values are mentioned in the question and indicated as a red dot in the following phase diagram of water) is not sufficient to make the water boil because the boiling point of water at this pressure is $T_\mathrm b=24.3\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$. The pressure would have to be reduced below $p=2.339\ \mathrm{kPa}\approx0.023\ \mathrm{atm}$ in order to make water boil at a temperature of $T=20\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$.

[image: phase diagram of water] source: [www.wolframalpha.com](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=water+20C+0.03atm)
<sup><sub>(Note that I don’t know how reliable the steam tables of WolframAlpha are. I only use it here by way of illustration but not for my calculations. Also note that the indicated value for STP is not in accordance with IUPAC recommendations.)</sub></sup>

Furthermore, the phase diagram of water shows that it is not possible to freeze water at such temperature and pressure. In order to freeze the water using the process that is described in the question, the pressure would have to be reduced below the triple point pressure of water, which is $p_\mathrm{tp}=611.657\ \mathrm{Pa}\approx0.006\ \mathrm{atm}$.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> “Enthalpy of Vaporization”, in *CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics, 97th Edition (2016),* William M. Haynes, ed., CRC Press/Taylor and Francis, Boca Raton, FL.

<sup>[2]</sup> “Enthalpy of Fusion”, in *CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics, 97th Edition (2016),* William M. Haynes, ed., CRC Press/Taylor and Francis, Boca Raton, FL.

<sup>[3]</sup> REFPROP – NIST Standard Reference Database 23, Version 9.0

<sup>[4]</sup> 2009 ASHRAE Handbook of Fundamentals, SI Edition

Answer (score 6):

You will need to know:

1. the heat capacity of water $C_p$
2. the latent heat of fusion of ice $L_f$
3. the latent heat of vaporization of water $L_v$

First determine how much heat must be lost to change the temperature from 20 to 0 using the heat capacity.

Next determine how much heat must be lost to change from 0 degree water to 0 degree ice using the latent heat of fusion.

Finally, add the two heats from above together to get a total heat loss, and use the heat of vaporization of water to calculate the amount of water evaporated that corresponds to this total heat loss.

Note: The above involves an approximation that the amount of water evaporated is relatively small.  In reality, once an infinitesimal portion of water evaporates, the amount remaining that needs to cool will be infinitesimally less than one kg.  If you are expected to know and use intergral calculus for your class, you may need to take into consideration how the mass is varying thoughout the process.

To calculate more accurately, break the problem is into two parts.

First, a mass m1 evaporates, to cool water from 20 degres to 0 degrees.

Let $m$ be the varible liquild mass during the process and temperature be $t$

$mC_pdt=L_vdm$

$C_p\int_{20}^{0}dt = L_v \int_{1}^{1-m1}(dm/m)$

The remaining mass is 1kg-m1

Second, a mass m2 evaporates, to freeze the remaining water.

$L_v m2 = L_f (1kg - m1 - m2)$

Comment: The question was, how much water did evaporate until freezing. So, heat of fusion is not necessary.

Comment: @Georg Because the question says "froze solid" I was picturing all the water freezing into a solid block.  If the person asking is only interested in how much water needs to evaporate to get to zero degrees C liquid, they can ignore the second step of the calculation.

Comment: I understand the question to be implying that water evaporates until all the ice is frozen.